# Why rosmake does not work?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new and I tried to use rosmake like this

> rosmake demo

But I get a problem

> [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...

> [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['demo']

> [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/senna/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130203-110054

> [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['demo'] to:

> []

> [ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['demo']

> [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

No idea why. Waiting for help. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54118/why-rosmake-does-not-work?/) by [Senna69](https://answers.ros.org/users/4124/senna69/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you have not set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. If demo is in your Desktop folder, first you should execute:

> export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/Desktop:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}

then you can use rosmake to execute:

> rosmake demo

---

Originally posted by [Hongbo Miao](https://answers.ros.org/users/4114/hongbo-miao/) with karma: 70 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3